In vitepress, how can i make it so that this text is not cramped and has a larger area to show itself in?
Here is my index.md file :
---
# https://vitepress.dev/reference/default-theme-home-page
layout: home

hero:
  name: "TP2"
  text: "Analyse du code du TP2 de Breno Mazzali Medeiros Tomazelli et de Philippe Bouchard"
  tagline: Analyses de code
  actions:
    - theme: brand
      text: Review du code de Breno Mazzali Medeiros Tomazelli
      link: /ReviewCodeBrenoMazzaliMedeirosTomazelli
    - theme: brand
      text: Review du code de Philippe Bouchard
      link: /ReviewCodePhilippeBouchard
---

This is what it looks like
The big white text in the middle is what i want to change
Tried to look online but did not really find something to help me

If you choose custom theme option with vitepress command line setup wizard, you will find css.style under .vitepress/theme folder. We can add style here :
div.VPHero.VPHomeHero > div > div > .text {
  word-spacing: 30px;
}

